# Passing a variable jquery .submit

Tags: php, jquery, forms, submit, selector

So essentially I'm submitting a form via jquery. There are multiple forms with multiple ID's using the format question_vote_[some_value].

I'm picking up the submission using the following selector:

```
$("form[id^='question_vote_']").submit(function(event){
    vote_on_question_recent(/* I need to add the value preceeding the id in here */);
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

Here's my form code:

```
<?php 
if ($question_choices)
{
    echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" value="' . $question_details['question_id'] . '" id="question_vote_' . $question_details['question_id'] .  '">';
      while($question_choice = $database->fetch_array($question_choices)) 
      {
        // do something with the $row
        echo '<input type = "radio" name = "radio_button_recent_' . $question_details['question_id'] . '" id = "radio_button_' . $question_details['question_id'] .  '_' . $question_choice['choice_id'] . '" value = "' . $question_choice['choice_id'] . '" /> <label for = "' . $question_choice['choice_text'] . '">' . $question_choice['choice_text'] . '</label><br>';
      }
    echo '<input type="submit" name="voteOnQuestion" value="Vote!" class="login_home_sub"></form>';
}
?>
```

I then have the following code for my 'vote_on_question_recent' function:

```
function vote_on_question_recent(question_id)
{   
    var form_name = 'vote_form';
    var choice_id = $('[name=radio_button_recent_' + question_id + ' ]:checked').val();

    if(choice_id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "API/index.php",
            data: {vote_form: form_name, question_id: question_id, choice_id: choice_id},
            success: function(result){
                if(result == 'success'){
                    alert(result);
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('error');
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr + ' / ' +  ajaxOptions + ' / Error:' + thrownError + ' Submitted choice:' + choice_id + ' question id:' + question_id);
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

So essentially I'm looking for some way to pass the 'question_id' to my javascript submit function, or get the actual id of the submitted form so I can parse it and get the ID that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `data-*` attribute to save the question id and use it in the submit handler to obtain the question id.

```
echo '<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" value="' . $question_details['question_id'] . '" id="question_vote_' . $question_details['question_id'] .  '" data-question="' . $question_details['question_id'] .  '">';
```

then

```
$("form[id^='question_vote_']").submit(function(event){
    vote_on_question_recent($(this).data('question'));
    event.preventDefault();
})
```